# PHP Prepared statements - Failing to retrieve the string from the database

Tags: php, mysql

I'm still fairly new to the prepared statements because it was brought to my attention by another user. I've been able to create a registration function that properly prepares the statement, binds it and then executes it. It goes into the database just fine. However, I'm not sure I understand how the login part would work. I'm trying to fetch a row and the result I keep getting is "1" but not the row + data inside the row. Any advice?

Database:
[image: Picture of database]

login.php (where the form is located)

```
<form id="loginform" class="form-horizontal" role="form" action="" method="post">

    <div style="margin-bottom: 25px" class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i></span>
        <input id="login-username" type="text" class="form-control" name="Lusername" placeholder="Username or Email">                                        
    </div>

    <div style="margin-bottom: 25px" class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></i></span>
        <input id="login-password" type="password" class="form-control" name="Lpassword" placeholder="Password">
   </div>

   <div class="input-group">
       <div class="checkbox">
           <label>
           <input id="login-remember" type="checkbox" name="remember" value="1"> Remember me
           </label>
       </div>
   </div>

   <div style="margin-top:10px" class="form-group">
   <!-- Button -->

       <div class="col-sm-12 controls">
       <button id="btn-login" type="submit" class="btn btn-success"><i class="icon-hand-right"></i>Submit</button>
       </div>
   </div>
</form>
```

script:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            $("#loginform").bind('submit',function() {
                var username = $('#login-username').val();
                var password = $('#login-password').val();
                $.post('scripts/loginFunction.php',{username:username, password:password}, function(data){
                    $('#signupsuccess').show();
                }).fail(function(){{
                    $('#signupalert').show();
                }});
                return false;
            });
        });
    </script>
```

loginFunction.php

```
<?php
require 'connection.php';
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

if($conn->connect_error){
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT `Username`, `Password` FROM `users` WHERE `Username` = ?");
$stmt->bind_param('s',$username);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->store_result();
echo $stmt->num_rows;
/*if($stmt->num_rows == 1){
    $result = $stmt->get_result();
    $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
    print_r($row);
    // here is where you could verify the password
    if(password_verify($password, $row['Password'])) {
        // good password
        echo 'all good!';
    }
} else {
    //echo "failed to find row";
}*/
?>
```

loginFunction.php that does work and queries the database properly

```
require 'connection.php';
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

if($conn->connect_error){
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
$query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username'";
$result = $conn->query($query);
if($result->num_rows == 1){
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
    if(password_verify($password, $row['Password'])){
        echo "Login successful!";
    }
    else{
        echo "Login failed.";
    }
}
```

---

EDIT: Here is the code you should use. Note how `$stmt` is carried throughout:

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT `Username`, `Password` FROM `users` WHERE `Username` = ?");
$stmt->bind_param('s',$username);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->store_result();
echo $stmt->num_rows;
/*if($stmt->num_rows == 1){
    $result = $stmt->get_result();
    $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
    print_r($row);
    // here is where you could verify the password
    if(password_verify($password, $row['Password'])) {
        // good password
        echo 'all good!';
    }
} else {
    //echo "failed to find row";
}*/
```

Comment: Don't mix `mysqli` with `mysql` use `$result->fetch_assoc()`

Comment: **Never store plain text passwords!** Please use PHP's [built-in functions](http://jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html) to handle password security. If you're using a PHP version less than 5.5 you can use the `password_hash()` [compatibility pack](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat). Make sure you ***[don't escape passwords](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36628418/1011527)*** or use any other cleansing mechanism on them before hashing. Doing so *changes* the password and causes unnecessary additional coding.

Comment: You are selecting literal strings instead of the values in the database columns. And the sql suggests that you are using plain-text passwords. You really shouldn't. Also note that unless you are on a windows server, `Username !== username`.

Comment: To echo what @jeroen is saying: column and table names should be back-ticked, not quoted.

Comment: To clear things up, the passwords are hashed in the registration. I use password_hash(String, PASSWORD_DEFAULT) but when I'm trying to use password_verify() it's not getting the databases string properly

Comment: Is `$password` the submitted password?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean, can you give an example or at least highlight the row where I'm going wrong? I've fixed the mysqli as spotted by apokryfos

Comment: Yes, $password is the password that is entered by the user.

Comment: If you use that to select from the database you will never get a result because the hashed password is stored in the database. Get rid of `AND password = ...` then fetch the hashed password to compare to the user submitted password with `password_verify()`. For example `password_verify($_POST['password'], $hashed_password)`

Comment: Okay, I've removed the password part but I keep getting this error: Trying to get property of non-object. It seems to be coming from this piece of code: if($result->num_rows == 1){
    $result->fetch_assoc();
    echo $row;
}

Comment: Did you change `bind_param` when you removed the password from the query?

Comment: I've updated the code above to reflect all the changes you guys have made.

Comment: You still have quotes around the column names. `'Username', 'Password'`

Comment: Removed quotes, still same occurring error. When I echo $result it just gives "1" still

Comment: Should I be using bind_result at all? I've seen it around and have tried it but it never seemed to work correctly.

Comment: You don't need bind result. [Did you read this?](http://jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html)

Comment: Yes I did, but I'm not sure about using PDO. Can I use their coding if I manipulate it into my variables/databases etc?

Comment: You don't have to use PDO - but the principle is the same from the logic standpoint. Your aren't getting any output because you never set `$row`. The code inside your if statement should be `$row = $result->fetch_assoc();    print_r($row);`

Comment: If I do what you say, it comes back with: Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on boolean because $result comes back as a 1.

Comment: Something is wrong with your query then. Can you edit your post and add your MySQL table creation script?

Comment: I haven't got a script to make the table. I'm just using a database that I setup like 3 days ago with various fields. I can take a screenshot of that and include that if that is any help?

Comment: Yes - please do that.

Comment: Now - edit your code to reflect the latest you're using. And use `print_r($row);` not `echo`

Comment: Now I'm getting: Trying to get property of non-object on the if statement. This whole thing is so confusing to me :/

Comment: I'm sorry for your confusion, it is tough to hash through things like this. Something I obviously missed was this: `WHERE username=` should be `WHERE Username=` (capital U) And you do not need `$stmt -> store_result();`

Comment: Still get the same error regardless of capital letter or not.

Comment: Is `users` the name of the table? Or does it have capitals too?

Comment: users does not have a capital

Comment: Apparently $result is a boolean and not an object, so it's not getting the strings properly from the database for some odd reason.

Comment: Try the code I just added.

Comment: Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on boolean. After adding your code

Comment: Made an edit, replaced `$result` with `$stmt`.

Comment: Fatal error: Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::fetch_assoc() after replacing the $result.

Comment: Alright, let's try thie new edit.

Comment: Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on boolean still occurring. I officially hate PHP

Comment: Run the above edit and tell me the results. And maybe consider PDO because it isn't as 'lengthy' or as 'wordy' and is much more portable.

Comment: After I run the code, in the network tab under the developer console it literally just says 1 (No quotations)

Comment: I am open to other ideas, I essentially do want to make a login form so if you have a recommendation for me to look at and start over from scratch in terms of the PHP, then I will.

Comment: It should echo 1 out to the web browser. Or are you using AJAX to send variables? If so, we may have been barking up the wrong tree and I would need to see the form your using and the AJAX call.

Comment: Yeah, I'm using AJAX I didn't expect that to be a problem, I'll update the code above to reflect the form and the AJAX

Comment: If the query is coming back as a Boolean then we may not be sending the Username properly.

Comment: Added the login form as well as the AJAX

Comment: How do you get `$username`?

Comment: I just added that now, as in it was in the PHP I just didn't post it in here yet

Comment: OK. Here is what I am going to suggest: use PDO as I have outlined in my post above. I think you'll find it easier and more consistent to use and it will provide you with better error messages and more portability. Focus on the PHP first (leave the jQuery and AJAX out) until you're comfortable with the concepts. Then add the AJAX. You have a lot of moving parts here and without being able to view them I cannot pinpoint where the problem creeps in.

Comment: Could you link me some PDO tutorials? And the reason why I'm using AJAX and Jquery is because it'll look more professional. Would you be happy to go into a discord server with me (Only using text chat) so we can live text rather than spamming this comment section? I have some questions that may be able to clear up the problem a lot faster.

Comment: [Start here](http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html). I understand why you're using AJAX, all I am saying is to get the PHP working first, then add the AJAX as an enhancement. I am not able to do chats from the environment where I am.

Comment: If I don't use a prepared statement, it works just fine. If I create a string with $query and then use the method query() then it logs in successfully. It's literally just when I add the prepared statements that the whole thing is not happy anymore.

Comment: `Username = ?` => `Username = :s`

Comment: Fatal error: Call to a member function bind_param() on boolean Even after changing it. It occurs on the line $stmt->bind_param('s', $username);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved the issue. When I went to fetch, I needed to store it in a separate variable than the one that the user is storing their entered password into. This can be reflected in the code below:

```
<?php
require 'connection.php';
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$dbusername = ""; //These two being the new variables
$dbpassword = "";

if($conn->connect_error){
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT Username, Password FROM users WHERE Username = ?;");
$stmt->bind_param('s', $username);
$stmt->execute();
if($stmt->execute() == true){
    $stmt->bind_result($dbusername, $dbpassword);
    $stmt->fetch();
    if(password_verify($password, $dbpassword)) {
        echo 'successful';
    }
    else{
        echo 'failed';
    }
}
else{
    echo 'failed';
}

?>
```